# Quadtree Performance: Square vs. Rectangular?

Tags: performance, quadtree

For a game I am writing, I am using a quadtree on a non-square map. The quadtree is used to look up neighboring units for collision detection, enemies to attack, nearest bases etc. within a given max. radius (circle).

What I wonder is, if there is a performance issue for having a quadtree made of rectangles rather than squares? Instead of dividing a square map into squares, a rectangular map is divided into rectangles of equal size in the quadtree.

**Square Quadtree on Rectangular Map**: a quadtree will be created filling the whole map but with empty/non used areas to the left or bottom depending on the orientation of the map (horizontal vs. vertical). This will require more squares for padding (?) and might have an impact on performance also during search?

**Rectangular Quadtree matching the Rectangular Map**: the quadtree will perfectly fill the map. However, will performance be impacted doing so? Given we search is using a radius which will fit into a square rather than a rectangle, it might result in slower searches? Also, both width & height have to be stored in each quadtree node as they are non-square.

**Question**:
Is it better to covert the quadtree to square form? I think using a rectangular squadtree might be OK but I am not sure?

**Screenshot (Rectangular Quadtree)**:
[image: Rectangular Quadtree]

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as you can easily compute the bounds, that is when an object is in a certain shape. This is trivial for any rectangles (including squares). It's also quite easy for circles (but it's not easy to cover the whole map with circles). It's also quite doable with triangles (graphic cards are super optimized at this). The nice thing about rectangle shapes is that you can easily divide them into other rectangles, which you need to get the `log n`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure both options are okay. From you example it also look like your data set is rather small, only a few dozen entries, maybe 100?

Some things to consider:

- As you mentioned: Rectangles require separate 'length' for x and y. The effect may be small but every additional bit of information slows down the structure because more data has to be move to and through the CPU.
- If you are storing objects in the quadtree that are (often) directly on rectangle borders, you need to be careful to implement the quadtree correctly:

  - Insertion: Inserting an item on the corner of four quadtrants, in which does it get inserted?
  - Queries/lookup: Inverse to insertion, any search that ends on the border may (unnecessarily, search all bordering qaudrants, which can be expensive.

In summary, the question is probably less about square/rectangular quadtrees but one should be careful when data is often on the quadrant borders.

Comment: There will be a couple hundred of objects. Yes, obviously the borders of the quadrants don't overlap, so adding is fine. However, come to think of it, yes, points laying close to borders/corners will make the search non-optimal if no radius is given. I'll add a priority queue for searching!

Comment: It sounds like you agree on my point, I repeat it just in case: Just be careful to say "quadrants don't overlap": if one quadrant has (0,0) to (1,1) and another quadrant (0,1) to (1,2), then in which quadrant lies the point (0,1), or (0.5,1), ... ? So quadrants do easily overlap, unless you always specify one of their corner coordinates as 'exclusive'. This can be hard to get right with floating point values (rounding errors, etc, ...).

Comment: No worries, I am using the second corner as 'exclusive', so there will be no doubt where an element has to be placed :)